# Telegram bot api how to schedule a notification?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've made a bot that gets today football matches and if the user wants he can get a reminder 10 min before a selected match.

```
while current_time != new_hour:
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
#return notification
    text_caps = "Your match starts in 10 minutes"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=text_caps)
```

Obviously while the loop runs i can not use another command . I am new to programming how could i implement this so i still get the notification but while that runs i can use other commands?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an [aiogram](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/) and you can make scheduled tasks with [aiocron](https://github.com/gawel/aiocron) (store users who wants to get notification in database or in global dict)

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a job.
Let's say you have a `CommandHandler("watch_match", watch_match)` that listens for a `/watch_match` conmmand and 10 minutes later a message is supposed to arrive

```py
def watch_match(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    ten_minutes = 60 * 10 # 10 minutes in seconds  
    context.job_queue.run_once(callback=send_match_info, when=ten_minutes, context=chat_id) 
    # Whatever you pass here as context is available in the job.context variable of the callback

def send_match_info(context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = context.job.context
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Yay")
```

A more detailed [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/timerbot.py) in the official repository
And in the official documentation you can see the `run_once` [function](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/timerbot.py)